# Python keyboard input

Tags: python, keyboard

I am beginner, how can I create a list of keys so that `Presskey` will randomly press a key from the list.
I need a list of numpad keys, keyboard keys he[enter link description here http://web-old.archive.org/web/20190801085838/http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html

```py
import ctypes
import time
import random

from pynput.keyboard import Controller
SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


# directx scan codes http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html
while (True):
    delay = random.uniform(0, 0.11)
    PressKey(0x4F)
    time.sleep(delay)
    ReleaseKey(0x4F)
    time.sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a simple solution for you using `pyautogui` module:

```
import pyautogui
import random
list_of_keys = ["num0", "num1", "num2", "num3", "num4", "num5", "num6", "num7", "num8", "num9"]
# or you can generate the keys using: ["num"+str(i) for i in range(10)]
key = random.choice(list_of_keys) # select random key from the list
pyautogui.press(key)
```

Basically I created list of numpad-keys (you can check out the pyautogui docs about key press [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys)), selected random key from the list using `random.choice(list)` and pressed on the key using `pyautogui.press(key)`.
**Good Luck!**